# Can you get a list of nested classes without using reflection in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Right now what I am doing is this:

```
public class Values {
   List<Line> _lines = new ArrayList<>();


   public class Line {

       public Line() {
           Values.this._lines.add(this):
       }

       public Values get_parent() {
           return Values.this;
       }
   }
}
```

This means that when I have a Line I can get the Values class it belongs to, and when I have Values by accessing the _lines instance variable I can get a list of all the lines that belong to the Values object.

This works fine and I have no problem with it, but just so I know , is there a way to get all the instances of Line created under each class of Values without using reflection?

As a side note I'm just saying without reflection because in the old days we always used to avoid reflection because it was too intense on the processor, this may have changed, I just still mistrust reflection and try to avoid it when possible

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Edit: I may have explained incorrectly what I wished to do, I'm sorry for that, here's what I was asking

The above code is what I'm using now, what I wish to use is something like this:

```
public class Values {
    public class Line {
    }
}
```

so assuming the above scenario, is there a way to do this without reflection?

```
Values v = new Values();
Line l1 = v.new Line();
Line l2 = v.new Line();
List<Line> = some magical way to retrieve all lines from v;
```

I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: you don't use reflection in this example, do you know that?

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking, you already have all instances of Line created for Values without reflection

Comment: Am curious - *mistrust reflection* , by you stating that, you are mistrusting the compiler. Why?

Comment: @t0mm13b - Reflection has almost nothing to do with the compiler...

Comment: @AdamSkywalker yes, and I know how to do the similar to what I did with reflection, I was just wandering if there is a way to do this without reflection

Comment: You can't get the required behaviour *with* reflection.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I will update my question to better explain it, english is not my primary language, sorry

Comment: @t0mm13b well when I started working professionally as a developer, when I tried to use reflection (that was back in the visual studio 2005 days developing applications for windows mobile) senior developers at the time kept saying, don't use reflection, it will make your program work slower , I guess it just stuck :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth are you sure about that? I'm almost positive I saw a way to do that with reflection in stack overflow when I was searching for an answer, I guess I may have misunderstood

Comment: There's no better way to do that better than you did

Answer (score 0):

Your `_lines` variable has the default access modifier which meants it's package private [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

So the answer is depends. If the class accessing the variable is from the same package then no you do not need reflection. If it's not then either reflection or a getter is what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry , I think I may have wrote it wrong, the example I showed is what I'm doing now, what I asked was, is there a way to do something like:  a = new Values();    and then say something like a.get_lines() but imagine not using a _lines variable in the Values class, I hope I explained it correctly